# How can I simplify the calling of this function?

Tags: c++, c, macros, variadic-functions

I've written (and use) my own string formatting function and I'd like to simplify the usage of the function, in a specific way shown below, but I'm unsure how.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// Object that can hold a copy of every type I want to print.
// Stores the copy in a union, with an enumeration to identify
// the type. any uses C++ constructors, but could also be implemented
// with C99 designated initializers, like so: https://ideone.com/ElQgBV
struct any
{
    ...
}

// The string format function requires the variable arguments
// to all be of the 'any' type for type safety and (essential for
// my purposes) positional printing.
// Arguments are accessed with a va_list, so essentially
// the variable arguments are treated as an array of any objects. 
char* format_function_(const char* fmt, ...);

// I call the above function with this macro that expands the
// variable arguments and adds a default-constructed sentinel
// at the end. The sentinel is used by the function to count
// how many arguments were passed.
#define format(fmt, ...) format_function_(fmt, __VA_ARGS__, any())

// Calling the function like so, via the above macro...
char* str = format("bits:%4b string:%1 %0 int:%3h float:%2.2\n",
    any("world"), any("hello"), any(3.14159f), any(42), any((u8)(1<<4)));
// ...returns this string:
// bits:00010000 string:hello world int:0000002A float:3.14
```

I'd like to be able to call the function like regular `*printf` style functions...

```
char* str = format("bits:%4b string:%1 %0 int:%3h float:%2.2\n",
    "world", "hello", 3.14159f, 42, (u8)(1<<4));
```

...with the use of the `any` object hidden away, possibly behind another macro.

How can I accomplish this?

**Edit/Update** The positional arguments are essential for my purposes. Any answer that does not preserve this functionality is not a valid answer.

Comment: Since you have tagged your question C++, I suggest you look into [template parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: [va_arg](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg)

Comment: @AlanAu `format_function_()` already does use va_list/va_arg/ etc. The arguments are 'wrapped' in the `any` object for type-safety (and other reasons). I've updated the question to include this information.

Comment: Have a convention in which the contents of the `fmt` string controls how many arguments the function tries to access.   That is what `print()` and `scanf()` family of functions do, and allows you to avoid having to supply a sentinel - and reduces need for the macro.

Comment: If you used templates you wouldn't have to use an `any` struct for type-safety. Or even a format string really, for that matter.

Comment: @Peter I could get rid of the sentinel and pass the argument count in some other way (originally it was just another function parameter) but the variable arguments need to be all of the `any` type; this is required by the inner workings of the `format_function_()` function. Removing the sentinel and passing the count in some other way will get rid of the macro, but won't change that the variable arguments still need to be `any` objects.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Templates might be where I end up going, but I avoid them where possible as they bloat compile times to an unacceptable (to me) degree. The format string provides numbered positions and output types (hex, binary and float precision are shown in the question). If you know any string formatting functions that can do this without a format string I'd like to take a look at them!

Comment: You shouldn't need any() - __VA_ARGS__ should take care of it.  Are you returning a malloc'd or new'd char array?  Do you have code that frees/deletes it otherwise you will get a memory leak.

Comment: @cup Without storing the arguments in the `any` type the format function doesn't know what the type of each argument is, and it needs to know! Unlike the printf family of functions, the format string does not (by design!) provide this information. For example, you do not need to say `%d` for an signed 32 bit integer or `%f` for 32 bit float, and then have to remember to change that later if the type of the argument changes. You just say, for example, `%2h` which means 'whatever the second argument is, insert a hexadecimal representation of it here'.

Comment: @x-x -  My comment does not change anything related to the need for your `any` type.   You are letting implementation details of the function drive the specification of the interface.   That is completely backward from a design perspective, and means you are imposing unnecessary constraints on the interface specification.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to CodeReview.SE?

Comment: A different topic... Why is there a C tag on this question? `any()` is clearly overloaded, and C doesn't support overloads. C isn't a subset of C++.

Comment: It's spelt "_initializers_".

Comment: @Gene The any object is nothing more than an enumeration and a union. True, I'm using C++ constructors, but C99 designated initializers could also do the same thing. Using only C99 the any object would look like this: ideone.com/ElQgBV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the C++11 standard there's something called [*parameter packs*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) which makes this very simple:

```
char* format_function(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    ...
}

template<typename ...T>
char* format(const char* fmt, T... values)
{
    return format_function(fmt, any(values)...);
}

...

char* str = format("bits:%4b string:%1 %0 int:%3h float:%2.2\n",
                   "world", "hello", 3.14159f, 42, (u8)(1<<4));
```

Comment: But the `any` approach has been proben to not be too safe at all... Anyway, long live C++11!

Comment: @KemyLand I don't argue about that :), but it does what the OP asks for (I think).

Comment: Anyway, shouldn't this question be on Code Review SE?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'ld like something like this? (Alert: C++11 code!)

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline void format() {}

void format(char ch) {
    fputc(ch, stdout);
}

void format(int i) {
    if(i < 0) {
        fputc('-', stdout);
        i = -i;
    }

    int divider = 1;
    while(i / divider >= 10)
        divider *= 10;

    do {
        int digit = i / divider;
        i -= divider * digit;
        divider /= 10;

        fputc('0' + digit, stdout);
    } while(divider > 0);
}

void format(const char *str) {
    fputs(str, stdout);
}

// TODO: Add more 'format()' overloads here!

template<typename FirstArg, typename... OtherArgs>
inline void format(const FirstArg &first, OtherArgs... others) {
    format(first);
    format(others...);
}
```

Then, you can simply...

```
const char *glorifiedIndex(int index) {
    switch(index % 10) {
        case 1:
            return "st";

        case 2:
            return "nd";

        case 3:
            return "rd";

        default:
            return "th";
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *const argv[]) {
    format("Hello, world!\n");
    format("My name is ", argv[0], ", and I was given ", argc - 1, " argument", argc != 2 ? "s" : "", ".\n\n");

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        format(i, glorifiedIndex(i), " argument: \"", argv[i], "\"\n");

    format("Goodbye, world!\n");
}
```

This is a more flexible and elegant model, for the following reasons:

- Semantically safe.
- Type safe.
- No `<cstdarg>` stuff.
- No `any` stuff.
- No incredibly badly-designed `iostream` stuff.
- It's too simple to implemet, and I mean **too much** :). Compare this few lines of code with a typical 3000+ lines long `printf.c`. The difference is in several orders of magnitude!
- You may have nostalgic moments relating with Java and Python.
- If you change the type of any expression for whatever reason (i.e, `int` to `unsigned`), the function accomodates itself to this.
- (Both good and evil) compiler optimizations can kick in easily.
- The user of the library may extended the abilities of the `format()` function by means of overloading it with user-defined types.
- This imposibilites the use of dynamic formats (this is intended for obvious security reasons).
- This forces you to create special functions for what I call bit-printing, i.e, printing in a machine-parsable way, rather than human-readable as `format()` did, does, and will do.
- You may use overloading features to extend this list yourself :).

Comment: My format function uses positional arguments (which are essential for my purposes) in the format string and formatting options (hex, binary, decimal precision etc) which when added to your example, *might* add too much complexity to what should be (IMO!) a simple operation. That said, I quite like this approach! :)

Comment: @x-x: That's the reason I have the second last reason. This function is *not* intended to provide formatting options, or even positional arguments (p.d: POSIX supports positional arguments for `printf()`, but the C++ standard doesn't). An elegant, templated equivalent for `printf()` has been desired since the beginnings of C++, with no success to the moment... other than `iostream`s...

Comment: The downside is that now you've got the variables and the hard-coded text all mushed together, internationalisation becomes a pain. `printf`-style format strings have definite advantages.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, *standard* `printf()` isn't too good for internationalisation, either. I'ld normally use a *pre*-preprocessor for this kind of stuff.

Comment: @KemyLand: How so? You can swap out the format strings at compile-time at will without having to hack about with your variables at the call site. How much better could it be?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The problem is actually very simple. The order of the arguments can be different for each locale/language in order for everything to make sense. Even worse, some languages have special grammatical rules that require special calculations on data. For example, in English: `printf("%s's %s", "John", "car")`; meanwhile, in Spanish: `printf("%s %s de %d", "El", "automóvil", "John")`. Thus, my solution has no longer that "disadvantage", as a *pre*-preprocessor is needed anyway for any of the two methods.

Comment: **Edit**: The "El" at the Spanish example is required, because Spanish uses either "El" or "La" as an article depending on the gender of the subject. Meanwhile, English uses "the" for both genders.